# python import package - subpackage should not show up in symbol table

Tags: python

I am wondering why the directory (subpackage) that holds submodules in a python package shows up as a symbol when the package is imported.  For instance, if I have this package:

```
PyModTest/                        Top-level package
          __init__.py             Initialize the package
          Source/                 Subpackage holding source files
                 __init__.py
                 WildMod.py        Submodule containing a function: 'WildFunc'
```

where the top level __init__.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Source.WildMod import WildFunc
```

and, for completeness' sake, the lower level __init__.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

__all__ = ["WildMod"]
```

OK, so now I open up the interpreter, import the module, and look at the symbols:

```
>>> import PyModTest
>>> dir(PyModTest)
['Source', 'WildFunc', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

SEE, the 'Source' module shows up, even though I never specifically imported it!

The only symbol (besides the private ones) that I want to see is my 'WildFunc'. Is there any way to hide the 'Source' package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things to note here:

- In Python, modules are actual objects, and the dot that appears between their names represents an actual attribute access
- You are doing a relative import, meaning that `Source` is actually `PyModTest.Source` (thanks to TokenMacGuy for pointing this out)

So: in order to import `PyModTest.Source.WildMod.WildFunc`, Python has to

1. import `PyModTest` (which was already done by you)
2. check and see if it has an attribute called `Source`, and if not, create the attribute by importing it from `PyModTest/Source/__init__.py`
3. check and see if that has an attribute called `WildMod`, and if not, create the attribute by importing it from `PyModTest/Source/WildMod.py`
4. check and see if that has an attribute called `WildFunc` (which it does)

Some relevant details are discussed in [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) and in the [Python language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).

> Deeper down in the mechanism, a dotted name import is split up by
>       its components.  For "`import spam.ham`", first an "`import spam`" is
>       done, and only when that succeeds is "`ham`" imported as a submodule
>       of "`spam`".

If you don't want to have a variable named `Source`, that's easy to fix: just `del Source` after you import the function. But bear in mind that it will prevent any code that runs later on from accessing `PyModTest.Source.<anything>` (except for `WildFunc`, since you have saved a reference to that). I would definitely suggest just ignoring the reference to `Source`, not deleting it, since it's not hurting anything.

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense.  Thanks for the suggestion on the 'del Source' :)

Comment: `Source` is a subpackage of `PyModTest`,  the implicit import is silently transformed into `from PyModTest.Source import ...`, and so the `Source` module must be added as an attribute of the `PyModTest` module.  If `Source` had been found outside the `PyModTest` package (unlikely, subpackages take precedence over `sys.path`), this would not have occured.  To avoid confusing yourself and others, always prefer absolute imports.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: ah, good catch. Somehow I missed the fact that this was a relative import.