# Python : from module import * in __init__

Tags: python, import, python-module

Here is a simple case: I want to define a module in python name robot. So, I have a folder named robot with these two files:

**__init__.py:**

```
from test import a
```

**test.py:**

```
a = "hello world"
```

Now, when I `import robot` in the interpreter, the `robot` namespace includes `test` and `a`. However, I only want it to include `a`. Why this odd behavior?

---

*EDIT:*

Here's a slightly more representative example of what I want to achieve:

Given the following files:

**__init__.py:**

```
from spam import a
import ham
```

**spam.py:**

```
a = "hello world"
```

**ham.py:**

```
b = "foo"
```

Can I have a `robot` namespace containing `a` and `ham` at its top level but not `spam`?

Comment: `import robot` imports the robot package (directory).  Since you're not specifying what to import, the entire package is imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created not just a module but a package.  A package contains its submodules in its namespace (once they have been imported, as you imported `test` here).  This is as it should be, since the usual way of using packages is to provide a grouping of several modules.  There's not much use to making a package with only one module (i.e., one contentful `.py` file) inside it.

If you just want a one-file module, just create a file called `robots.py` and put your code in there.

Edit: See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540290/how-to-organize-multiple-python-files-into-a-single-module-without-it-behaving-l/12540337?noredirect=1#comment24132597_12540337).  The answer is that you should in general not worry about excluding module names from your package namespace.  The modules are *supposed* to be in the package namespace.  If you want to add functions and stuff from submodules as well, for convenience, that's fine, but there's not really anything to be gained by "covering your tracks" and hiding the modules you imported.  However, as described in the answers to that question, there are some hackish ways to approximate what you want.

Comment: I see, thanks. I've edited my original post to be more representative of what I actually want to achieve. I do have some submodules, but I also want some functions to be exposed at the top level. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @user2364719: I edited my answer.  The basic answer is that, although you can sort of hack it, you shouldn't worry about removing modules from the package namespace, because modules are *supposed* to be in the package namespace.  You can add other things to the package namespace, but the base purpose of the package namespace is to hold the modules, and Python doesn't provide a straightforward way to avoid that.

Comment: Alright then, i'll import the "core" functionality from a _core.py so it's sort of hidden. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking how to import specific modules or functions?

test.py:

```
import robot.spam.a
import robot.ham
```

Don't import the entire package.

Comment: Then I would have robot.spam.a and robot.ham. Sorry for not being clear, but what I'd like to be to have a sort of "core" file that includes all the functions and classes I want available at the top level of the robot package/module.

Comment: Make `robot` a module (a .py file).  Define `a`, `test`, `ham` and `spam` inside of robot. Then you'll have `robot.a`, `robot.spam`, `robot.ham`, etc.  For what you're wanting to do, keep everything in the same directory.

Comment: Makes sense, but in reality the entire thing is ~10k loc. Separating it in submodules is convenient for organisation, and I don't always need to import everything (sometimes I only need ham).