# How to organize and execute OOP python files on Pycharm like Csharp on visual studio

Tags: python, oop, pycharm

So in visual studio, you can divide you C sharp code in multiple classes that are stored in individual .cs files, but are members of the same namespace. I want to try that with Python on the pycharm environment. However i am not sure how my terminal (I use Manjaro Linux) or the pycharm console would appropriately identify all those files as part of the same project when executing my main python script.

Comment: Read about [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). The [packages section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) might be especially helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540290/how-to-organize-multiple-python-files-into-a-single-module-without-it-behaving-l

Answer (score 0):

You can see below the standard call from file

1st step - create a new file for example: `funcs.py`

with:

```
def first():
  print('hey I'm the first one')
```

2nd step - create a new python file in the same folder like `menu.py`

and you can call the `funcs.py` from `menu.py` like this:

```
import funcs.py

funcs.first()
```